# Понимание определения "работающий код" в описании метки [инспекция-кода]

Tags: обсуждение, предложение, метки, описание-метки, инспекция-кода

Столкнулся с непониманием, когда задал свой вопрос с меткой [инспекция-кода](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/%d0%b8%d0%bd%d1%81%d0%bf%d0%b5%d0%ba%d1%86%d0%b8%d1%8f-%d0%ba%d0%be%d0%b4%d0%b0). Ссылка на вопрос: [BackgroundService не может корректно завершиться](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/1199515/212981). Метку уже удалил.

Пользователь сообщества [aepot](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/users/373567/aepot) в комментариях сделал правильное замечание по поводу того, что мой вопрос не соответствует метке, поскольку код **не является работающим**. Однако для меня не совсем понятно, что такое *"работающий код"*. В описании метки есть предисловие:

> Вопросы по этой метке должны содержать только **работающий код**. Если у
> вас вопрос "почему не работает" — не ставьте эту метку. Обязательно
> опишите реализуемую функциональность и назначение кода. Используйте
> стандартный для языка стиль кодирования — имена функций и переменных,
> отступы, пробелы и прочее. Подробная инструкция есть в полном
> описании.

В описании метки нет никаких критериев работающего кода, лишь рекомендации. В комментариях к своему вопросу я высказался:

> а что означает по вашему "рабочий код"? ... Код запускается? Определенно, да. Код
> выполняет свои основные функции? Определенно, да. Единственное, что
> код не всегда корректно справляется с задачей завершения работы.

Хочу понять и предлагаю внести в описание метки определение понятия работающего кода.

Comment: Вот вы строите дом, закончили его, красивый, хороший (по вашему мнению), но вас смущает тот факт, что вы потратили уйму времени на постройку лестницы на 2-й этаж, вы израсходовали много лишнего ресурса (например раствора, кирпича, досок) и для того, чтоб в будущем не совершить эту ошибку, зовете человека, который разбирается в этой теме, тот говорит, что камень можно было класть иначе, тогда будет лучше получаться и меньше уйдет ресурса. Другими словами, вы сделали полностью рабочий проекта, но с некоторыми погрешностями и хотите понять как эти погрешности избежать в дальнейшем.

Comment: Не знаю, что вкладывали в это авторы фразы, но лично для меня «рабочий код» — такой, который успешно справляется со всеми поставленными перед ним задачами. А если что-то там «не может корректно завершиться», то код уже не очень рабочий (но если на это глубоко плевать и корректное завершение в поставленную задачу не входит, то рабочий :)